# Avoid Negative and brackets using php

Tags: php, function

```
<?php
 $money= -20
echo money_format('%(19.2n',$money).'Only';
?>
```

I have tried using `money_format` to avoid negative sign in php,the above code removes the negative sign but it adds brackets to the given values.I want to eliminate the brackets as well as the negative sign.For instance changing `-20` to `20.00`.Any help on how to fix this.Thanks

Comment: brackets is a standard way of displaying something that is negative, if you want to have no such format then multiply the result by `-1` and display

Comment: @DevZer0 I'd use `abs` instead, to make sure positives do not get negative.

Comment: @DevZer0 This would also make normal, valid, positive numbers into a negative one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `abs()`.

This absolutes the value which removes negatives.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want negative values, don't feed negative values to `money_format`. Make them "unnegative" using [`abs`](http://php.net/abs).

Answer (score 0):

use [abs()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_math_abs.asp) function which helps you to remove negatives.